# Problems at White Gloves Society

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

When you visit Ultra-Luxe and meet the White Gloves Society members there is a mission that asks to look for an investigator.

The problem is that as soon as I enter inside its room I am attacked by two guards and die because unarmed. How can I win against them? I tried many times but it seems I do very small damage to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I played through this it took many tries, so first and foremost: *save often*. If you take one of the guys out, save before you start on the next one.

There are a few ways to do this:

- Take some Unarmed books with you. These will help if you haven't focussed much on skilling in Unarmed.
- Some people in the Mojave will teach you special unarmed moves. The NCR Ranger (with the injury) in Novac will teach you one, for example. These may come in handy here.
- Run away and heal up outside of the casino. It is entirely possible to escape and get out alive, but the two men will still be there when you return.
- Holdout weapons & the sneak skill. You might be able to pull off sneak attack criticals, which are extremely powerful.

Unarmed companions are also extremely useful when dealing with this situation - Veronica, for example.

Comment: Also, take some chems, like Buffout, and some magazines, like Boxing Times.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that I had left Boone and Rex somewhere out. I returned with them and was quite easy to kill guards.

Answer (score 0):

A modest investment in sneak is very useful here, and it works with almost every build (not big guns, but regular guns, energy weapons, melee, unarmed...) If your sneak skill is 50+ (so 25 base +stealth suit, +book), you can walk in with a powerful holdout weapon. I happened to have "Lucky" and Mk2 Reinforced Combat Armor when I walked into that room, and so it went like this:

I picked up the matches, "Hmmmm, matches..." 
**WHONK** "What was that?" 
**WHONKWHONK** "It's like something is hitting me...Heeeey, I lost a hitpoint!" 
I turn around to see two creepy Luxor's. One whonks me with his cane.
"OH HELL NO!" Pull out my .357, VATS HEADSHOTx2, Switch, HEADSHOTx2

'Course, then I screwed up something later in the quest chain, and ended up having to do that to damn near everyone in the hotel.